# What kinds of techniques do autopilots of autonomous cars use?

Tags: neural-networks, applications, reference-request, autonomous-vehicles

What kinds of techniques do autopilots of autonomous cars (e.g. the ones of Tesla) use? Do they use reinforcement learning? Which types of neural network architecture do they use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will focus on Tesla's autopilots in this answer (because that's the only specific autopilot you mention).

In [their website](https://www.tesla.com/autopilot), they mention the basic technologies underlying the current autopilots, which includes deep neural networks.

> To make use of a camera suite this powerful, the new hardware introduces an entirely new and powerful set of vision processing tools developed by Tesla. Built on a **deep neural network**, Tesla Vision deconstructs the car's environment at greater levels of reliability than those achievable with classical vision processing techniques.

So, they are probably using convolutional neural networks for the computer vision tasks.

There's also [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Autopilot) completely dedicated to Tesla's autopilot.

Comment: So i read that wikipedia page.they don't mansion the particular software, just for interest do you have any idea how car moves?i mean i think there is an RL agent who manages gas and stop pedals and drives car.like some people said they don't use RL, so what else they should be using?

Comment: They are probably using a combination of different ideas and tools. Maybe there's some technical paper that talks about it. RL isn't probably ready for real-world applications like autonomous vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

They definitely don't use RL.

My guess is a mix of NN for segmentation, lidar, radar and how for perception.

Once object detection has been performed they use a trajectory generator and MPC.

There is an autonomous car class on Coursera that goes over this.

Comment: Your guess? This is not a question that should lead to speculative answers. It's a question looking for facts. So, an answer to this question requires citations. I will remove my downvote once you provide those citations.

Comment: why not? so then what is controlling the rudder? then what decides when to accelerate and when to stop?

Comment: i mean recognition is obvious but source of it's engine is not.can you provide more additional detailes?